# Log the output of a gql tagged template literal?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

This is a graphql command am I executing on the client:

```
        const result = yield client.mutate({
            /* tslint:disable:max-line-length */
            mutation: gql`
                mutation licensemutation($distributor: String, $licenseType: String, $duration: String, $userId: String) {
                    addLicenseCode(distributor: $distributor, licenseType: $licenseType, duration: $duration, userId: $userId) {
                        code,
                        distributor, 
                        duration, 
                        oneTimeUsage, 
                        validFrom, 
                        validTo
                    }
                }
            `,
            /* tslint:enable */
            variables: {
                userId: username,
                distributor: distributor,
                licenseType: 'Premium',
            },
        });
```

How can I log the output of the gql tagged template literal to the console?

Comment: [just console.log it](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tag#gql)? graphiql sends query and variables as separate objects - you can check this in browser network tab - graphql-tag parses only query part

Comment: When I log the gql tagged template literal an object is outputted. I would like to log the resulting string that will be sent to the backend, or a string representation of what is sent.

Comment: [apollo devtools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apollo-client-developer-t/jdkknkkbebbapilgoeccciglkfbmbnfm) ?

Comment: In case you want to see your variables replaced: This is done on the server, not on the client. The only AST manipulation that `gql` does is replacing fragment references in `gql\`query { ...Frag } ${Frag}\`` where it simply merges the operations of the documents.